# How to test that Redux's dispatch() has been called in React Component (Jest + Enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a lot of functional React components that call `dispatch()` (Redux). The `dispatch()` function itself is passed in by react-redux's `useDispatch()` hook.

As a simplified example:

```
const LogoutButton: FC = () => {
  const dispatch: Dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  return (
   <button onClick={() => {
     console.log("Clicked...") // To check that onClick() simulation is working
     dispatch(authActions.logout())  
   }}>
   LOGOUT
   </button> 
  )
}
```

Using Jest and Enzyme, what do I need to do to be able to assert `expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(authActions.logout)`?

I don't have a function for mocking the store or use redux-mock-store. Instead, I wrap the components in a Root component I made for testing. It's the same as my real Root component, but takes props for setting up the test's initial store (and history.location):

```
const TestRoot: FC<RootProps> = ({ children, initialState = {}, initialEntries = defaultLocation }) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={initialEntries}>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

which is used in tests to set up the Enzyme-wrapped component like:

```
wrappedLogoutButton = mount(
  <TestRoot initialState={initialState}>
    <LogoutButton />
  </TestRoot>
);
```

This set up works nicely for me (so far) and I don't want to change it if I don't have to. I did try injecting a redux-mock-store mock store into TestRoot, but that messed up every single test suite I've written.

I've tried numerous ways of mocking or spying on both `dispatch()` and `useDispatch()` but I haven't been able to see the mock being called. The `onClick()` simulation is working because I can see "Clicked..." being logged. Here's an example test (real code, not simplified example):

```
test('should log learner out', () => {
    const event = {
      preventDefault: () => {},
      target: { textContent: en.common['log-out-title'] } as unknown,
    } as React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>;

    const wrappedLogOut = wrappedMenuDrawer.find(ListItem).at(3).find('a');

    // @ts-ignore
    act(() => wrappedLogOut.prop('onClick')(event));

    // TODO: test authService.logout is called
    // assert that dispatch was called with authActions.logout()
    expect(amplitude.logAmpEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('from main menu', { to: 'LOGOUT' }); // This assertion passes
  });
```

Methods/variations I've tried of mocking/spying on dispatch, based on documentation, Medium posts and similar questions on Stack Overflow, include:

```
import * as reactRedux from 'react-redux'
const spy = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, 'useDispatch'
```

```
import store from '../../store';
const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch')
```

```
const mockUseDispatch = jest.fn();
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useDispatch: () => mockUseDispatch.mockReturnValue(mockDispatch),
}));

// or...

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useDispatch: () => mockUseDispatch,
}));

mockUseDispatch.mockReturnValue(mockDispatch) // inside the actual test
```

Comment: *what do I need to do to be able to assert* - see https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html . *The onClick() simulation is working because I can see "Clicked..." being logged* - it's not, and there's no click simulation in the code you posted. console.log and dispatch are called on render, not on click, and btw, there's syntax mistake in onClick, it wouldn't compile. It should be `onClick={() => dispatch(authActions.logout())}`, not `onClick={dispatch(authActions.logout())}`.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. The test code I posted was not the complete test, just my attempts to mock/spy on dispatch. I've been using variations on `act(() => wrappedButton.prop('onClick')());` to simulate the click. The syntax mistake you spotted (nice catch) was a typo on the StackOverflow post, but not on my actual code.

I'll fix the typo and add in an actual test from my code. Let me know if you still think there's a problem with simulating the click, but I don't think there is.

Comment: It's `a` in one place and `button` in another. *I've been using variations* - what variations exactly? Calling onClick directly is not really click simulation (but it may be ok). Also, you don't need `act` with Enzyme. Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem? The question contains only truncated and inconsistent snippets that don't give an idea what you did wrong. If there's error message for failed assertion, please, post it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do so. AFAIK:

- You can mock useDispatch hook to return your own fake dispatch function.
  I used in my test code for my own React library to help with managing binding dispatch to actions. Here it is [hooks.test.tsx](https://github.com/sidecus/roth.js/blob/master/src/hooks.test.tsx).
- Since you are wrapping your component with a test React store, you can also replace store.dispatch with a fake function directly. See [here](https://gist.github.com/krawaller/e5d40217658fa132f3c3904987e467cd) for a discussion.

Benefit of the first one is that you can easily mock more stuff from react-redux as needed.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I went with the second option. I added `makeTestStore()` into the `TestRoot`, and then I could access that `store` with the mocked `dispatch()` from within a `test` block with: `const store = wrappedMenuDrawer.find(Provider).prop('store');`

Comment: Discussion link is broken.