# I am trying to mock redis with jest and javascript and when I access redis.mock.instance[0] it is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock redis with jest and javascript and when I access redis.mock.instance[0] it is always empty

RedisWrapper.js:
`

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const REDIS_USER_TTL = 604800;

class RedisWrapper {
    constructor(host = 'redis', port = 6379, db = 3) {
        this.redis = new Redis({host: host, port: port, db: db})
    }

    async get(key) {
        return this.redis.get(key)
    }

    async set(key, data) {
        this.redis.set(key, data)
    }
}

module.exports = RedisWrapper
```

ethermail_paywall.spec.js:
`

```
const {validateEmailWeb2} = require("../../plugins/ethermail_paywall");
const {PaywallConfigurationEnum} = require("../../enums/paywallEnum");
const RedisWrapper = require("../../helpers/redis-wrapper");

jest.mock("../../helpers/redis-wrapper")

test('receiver with configuration: FILTER_HIGH_SECURITY_DOMAINS', async () => {

    const userReceiver = {
        config_web2: PaywallConfigurationEnum.FILTER_HIGH_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
        address: '0x261d37e08dc152e8b040bfff6278449910825f2b'
    }
    const domainSender = 'gmail'
    const prefix = 'paywall_domain_'

    `const redisInstance = RedisWrapper.mock.instances[0]`
    const mockMongodb = jest.fn()


expect(await validateEmailWeb2(userReceiver, userReceiver.address, domainSender, mockMongodb, RedisWrapper, prefix)).toBe(true)
```

``

When I go through this line of code, it returns empty and should bring me a mocked instance:

`const redisInstance = RedisWrapper.mock.instances[0]`

try to export the class in different ways like for example export default but this gives me an error saying the token is not recognized.

I want to achieve that it returns the mocked instance when it passes through the line "const redisInstance = RedisWrapper.mock.instances[0]"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mock a class/constructor but also get an instance of mocked implementation. Why don't you have your own mock directly?

```js
test('receiver with configuration: FILTER_HIGH_SECURITY_DOMAINS', async () => {
   /*
  your other mocks
*/
  const redisInstanceMock = {
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue("value you want to be returned on get"),
    set: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
  }

  const result = await validateEmailWeb2(userReceiver, userReceiver.address, domainSender, mockMongodb, redisInstance, prefix)
  expect(result).toBe(true)
}
```

Comment: If you use enzyme take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568505/how-to-test-that-reduxs-dispatch-has-been-called-in-react-component-jest-e